# Overide html formatting FormField in WTForms

Tags: wtforms

Using wtforms I am trying to format the following form. So I have evrything working but I do not need the html table which 'FormField' gets wrapped in - so how to bypass/override that?

```
class WeekdayHoursForm(BaseForm):

   hours = [(str(x+1), str(x+1)) for x in range(12)]
   mins=[('00',':00'),('15',':15'),('30',':30'),('45',':45')]

   fromHour = SelectField('',choices=hours)
   fromMin  = SelectField('',choices=mins)
   toHour   = SelectField('',choices=hours)
   toMin    = SelectField('',choices=mins)
   closed   = BooleanField('Closed','0')

class AddListingForm(BaseForm):
   monday    = FormField(WeekdayHoursForm)
   tuesday   = FormField(WeekdayHoursForm)

   etc...
```

My View

```
<div class="wrapper-block weekday" id="mon">
   {{ form.monday.label }} {{ form.monday() }}  
</div>

<div class="wrapper-block weekday" id="tues">
   {{ form.tuesday.label }} {{ form.tuesday() }}
</div>
```

I have omitted the generated HTML but I can paste it in if needed  - I am aware wtforms FormField uses a 'TableWidget'  but I dont know where to set this to `'with_table_tag = False'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every [`wtforms.fields.Field`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field) subclass takes a keyword argument named `widget` that can be used to override the rendering of the field.  You can read more about the available WTForms widgets [in their docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/widgets.html).

If you just wanted to use a list rather than a table you could use the built in ListWidget:

```
# ... snip ...
class AddListingForm(BaseForm):
   monday    = FormField(WeekdayHoursForm, widget=ListWidget)
   tuesday   = FormField(WeekdayHoursForm, widget=ListWidget)
```

Comment: Thanks - I consulted the docs but still wasn't sure where/how to pass in the widget.